# Togglz Admin Console and Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, togglz

I'm trying to enable Togglz Console in my Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6 application.

I added the following Maven dependency:

```
<!-- Togglz Admin Console -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
    <artifactId>togglz-console</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and added the following `application.properties`:

```
server.port: 8080
server.servlet.context-path= /api
#Togglz
togglz.console.enabled=true
togglz.console.path=/togglz-console
togglz.console.secured=true
togglz.console.feature-admin-authority=ROLE_1
```

Right now I unable to access http://localhost:8080/api/togglz-console with the following error:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:870) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) [thymeleaf-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) [thymeleaf-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:355) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:188) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
```

Except for Togglz Admin Console issue, everything else with Togglz Features works fine. How to properly enable Togglz Admin Console?

Comment: The stack trace isn't related to Togglz at all? Any `caused by` block in the full stack trace?

Comment: I figured out that by default Togglz now is working to the management port. I have disabled this behavior and now able to reach Togglz console at the mentioned URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get it working you should add the following property:

```
togglz.console.use-management-port=false
```